# Fix CreateJS in Adobe Animate HTML5 Ad for IE9/10

Tags: html, internet-explorer-9, createjs, animate-cc

I'm creating an HTML5 ad in Adobe Animate CC, which in itself is fine.

I'm trying to put in place browser fallbacks.  When I test the ad, it displays fine except for in Internet Explorer <= 10.

What's odd is that, per [this whitepaper](http://blogs.adobe.com/animate/files/2016/03/AdobeAnimateToTheRescue_CoryHudson_Final2.pdf) by Cory Hudson, Ad Expert™, IE8 is the last browser in that progression that didn't support `<canvas>` and I do believe that.

Looking at IE9 and IE10 specifically, I find that the canvas element does show up, with the background color that I specified in Adobe Animate CC.  There's just no elements or animations of any kind showing up in it.

[CreateJS](http://createjs.com/) is advertised as supporting IE9+, but is there something specific that could be causing it to fail on IE9/10?  I recognize that I'm dealing with Animate CC's generated JS code that *uses* CreateJS, but still any pointers would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Man, I got the same problem!

I noticed that before last Animate's update, HTML5 works fine on IE <= 10, so I compared the files and get a hugh diference on the .HTML files.

One thing that was add on last update is "support HiDPI and Retina displays", so Adobe change the function "handleComplete" (in HTML file) and put some new lines on it.

One var of this function (pRatio) get a window attribute (window.devicePixelRatio), and on IE <= 10 this return undefined. There is our problem!

To HTML5 work, put this line before the line that set canvas.width, like this:

```html
if(pRatio == undefined) pRatio = 1; //work on IE <= 10
canvas.width = w*pRatio*sRatio;
```

I think this will be fixed soon, but until that day, that's a solution.
Bye

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I have upvoted it, and next time I need to make an ad with Animate I will try it out. If it works I will accept your answer then. (Sorry, just not in a position to verify your answer right now.)